# At what points on $y=3x^3+14x^2+3x+8$ does the tangent pass through the origin.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Stumped by a simple question.
At what points on $$y=3x^3+14x^2+3x+8$$ does the tangent pass through the origin.

I got 3x+8 as the equation but it doesn't pass through the origin. I don't know what should i do now. Can someone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to find an equation for the tangent line?

Comment: yes, i know. y=mx+c. for 'm' differentiate the equation and solve x. then sub in a point and solve for 'c'

Answer (score 1):

This is no an answer, but a series of questions. Answer them in sequence and tell me if you get stuck on some point.

1. Do you know what derivatives are?
2. If $f(x)$ is some function, what is the slope of the tangent at point $(x_0, f(x_0))$?
3. What is the equation of the tangent at point $(x_0, f(x_0))$?
4. In your case, what is $f(x)$?
5. Therefore, what is the equation of the tangent at point $(x_0, f(x_0))?$
6. When does a line, defined by the formula $y=kx+n$, pass through the origin?
7. Putting together answers from 5 and 6, what equation do you get?

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain a bit further because i still didn't got the points where the tangent pass through the origin

Comment: @Rahul Well, did you answer the questions? Are you stuck at one of the questions? Don't expect me to solve the problem for you. I am here to help *you* solve the problem, and I gave you the blueprint. If you tell me where you are stuck, I can help you further. Did you answer questions 5 and 6?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to calculate the tangent line.
$$
y'=9x^2+28x+3
$$
Then the gradient of the tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $m=9x_0^2+28x_0+3$. The equation of the tangent line is therefore: 
$$
y=y_0+m(x-x_0)
$$
You are looking for points $(x_0,y_0)$ that satisfy: $0=y_0-mx_0$, namely:
$$
y_0=9x_0^3+28x_0^2+3x_0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We need points on the curve $(x,  y(x))$ such that

$$\frac{y(x) - 0}{x - 0} = y'(x)$$

which we could solve by simplifying into a cubic equation.